# how comes that 2 python's multiprocessing processes stay at a single processor

Tags: python, multiprocessing

My python script, which is essentially like the example code below, fails to use two processors for two independent processes create via the `multiprocessing` module.

Two processes are created, executed, and joint, but all happens on a single core.

I have trouble in understanding what is the problem, since **on a different machine everything is as expected**. `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` returns `4` on either machine.

So my question is a bit vague: What might be the reason, that the processes do not use all available processors.

Example code:

```
import numpy as np
import multiprocessing

n = 10
mat = np.random.randn(n, n)
vec = np.ones((n, 1))


def compprod():
    print np.dot(mat, vec)
    return


def compsum(times):
    print times*vec
    return

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compprod)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=compsum, args=(n, ))

p1.start()
p2.start()

p1.join()
p2.join()

print 'done'
```

Comment: If the the target functions (e.g. `compprod`, `compsum`) end quickly, the both processes may end up running on the same core.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But this is probably not the case in my example. As the function take hours to terminate. In fact I really can observe two parallel processes but on the same core. Did I get you right?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414027/multiprocessing-pool-makes-numpy-matrix-multiplication-slower. Numpy changes CPU affinity when it's imported, and that can lead to it being stuck running on a single CPU, even with `multiprocessing`. The link provided shows you how you can get around this. I can't say for certain that's what you're hitting, but its worth a try.