# Numpy: Multiprocessing a matrix multiplication with pool

Tags: python, numpy, pool

I am trying to calculate a dot product with pool

```
pool = Pool(8)
x = np.array([2,3,1,0])
y = np.array([1,3,1,0])
print np.dot(x,y) #works
print pool.map(np.dot,x,y) #error below

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

also tried

```
ne.evaluate('dot(x, y)') 


TypeError: 'VariableNode' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is, unfortunately, not possible in the ways you're trying to do it, and is not possible in a simple way either.

To make things worse, the multiprocessing.pool documentation for Python 2.7 is utterly wrong and essentially lies for `Pool.map`: it isn't at all equivalent to the builtin `map`. The builtin `map` can take multiple argument iterators to pass to the function, while `Pool.map` can't... this has been known and not fixed or documented in the docstring for `Pool.map` since [*at least 2011*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/python-multiprocessing-pool-map-for-multiple-arguments). There's a partial fix, of course, in Python 3 with starmap...

Honestly, though, the multiprocessing module isn't terribly useful for speeding up numerical code. For example, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414027/multiprocessing-pool-makes-numpy-matrix-multiplication-slower) for a long discussion of situations where many numpy operations were *slower* when done through multiprocessing.

However, there's another issue here as well: you can't simply parallelize like this. `map` takes lists/iterators of arguments and applies a function to each in turn. That's not going to do what you want: in this case, try `map(np.dot,x,y)`, and note that what you get is simply the product of each element of x and y as a list, not the dot product. Running a function many times in parallel is easy. Making that function parallel on a single call is hard, as it requires making the function itself parallel. In this case, that would usually mean rewriting the function.

**Except np.dot is actually already parallelized**, if you have a version of numpy with blas or atlas (try `np.__config__.show()`). You don't actually need to do any work at all in that case: `np.dot(x,y)` should *already* use all your cores without any work!

I should note that this is, however, restricted to some `dtypes`; floats are generally the most supported. On my computer, for example, behold the striking differences between `float` and `int`:

```
In [19]: a = np.matrix(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(1000,1000)),dtype='int')

In [20]: b = a.astype('float')

In [23]: %timeit np.dot(a,a)
1 loops, best of 3: 6.91 s per loop

In [24]: %timeit np.dot(b,b)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.1 ms per loop
```

For numexpr (and in asking questions, it's useful to point out what abbreviations you are using to those who might not know), there's only a very limited set of supported functions; check the documentation for a list. The error you get is because `dot` isn't a supported function. Since you're dealing with 1D arrays, and dot is pretty simple to define, the following will work: `ne.evaluate('sum(x*y)')`. I doubt, however, that you're planning on only using 1D arrays.

If you really want to parallelize things on a large scale, I'd suggest using IPython, and its [parallel system](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/parallel/), which unlike Python's multiprocessing, is actually useful for numerical work. As an added bonus, it can also parallelize across computers. However, this sort of parallelization is usually only useful for things that take a while per run; if you just want to use all your cores for simple things, then it's probably best to hope that numpy has multiprocessor support for the functions you want to use.

Comment: thanks, initially I thought numpy should be taking care of parallelism, but it is very slow, I have doubts. When I run the  code on IDLE, and check the CPU usage with htop, I see only 1 core is hitting 100%, the others stay at 1%. The output of np.__config__.show()) blas_info:
    libraries = ['blas']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
lapack_info:
    libraries = ['lapack']
    library_dirs = ['/usr/lib']
    language = f77
atlas_threads_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

Comment: See the edit I just made: if you're using ints, as you are above, that may be your problem.