# Minimize overhead in Python multiprocessing.Pool with numpy/scipy

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, pool

I've spent several hours on different attempts to parallelize my number-crunching code, but it only gets slower when I do so. Unfortunately, the problem disappears when I try to reduce it to the example below and I don't really want to post the whole program here. So the question is: what pitfalls should I avoid in this type of program?

(Note: follow-up after Unutbu's answer is at the bottom.)

Here are the circumstances:

- It's about a module that defines a class `BigData` with a lot of internal data. In the example there is one list `ff` of interpolation functions; in the actual program, there are more, e.g., `ffA[k]`, `ffB[k]`, `ffC[k]`.
- The calculation would be classified as "embarrassingly parallel": the work can be done on smaller chunks of data at a time. In the example, that's `do_chunk()`.
- The approach shown in the example would result, in my actual program, in the worst performance: about 1 second per chunk (on top of 0.1 second or so of actual calculation time when done in a single thread). So, for n=50, `do_single()` would run in 5 seconds and `do_multi()` would run in 55 seconds.
- I also tried to split up the work by slicing the `xi` and `yi` arrays into contiguous blocks and iterating over all `k` values in each chunk. That worked a bit better. Now there was no difference in total execution time whether I used 1, 2, 3, or 4 threads. But of course, I want to see an actual speedup!
- This may be related: [Multiprocessing.Pool makes Numpy matrix multiplication slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414027/multiprocessing-pool-makes-numpy-matrix-multiplication-slower). However, elsewhere in the program, I used a multiprocessing pool for calculations that were much more isolated: a function (not bound to a class) that looks something like `def do_chunk(array1, array2, array3)` and does numpy-only calculations on that array. There, there was a significant speed boost.
- The CPU usage scales with the number of parallel processes as expected (300% CPU usage for three threads).

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import numpy as np, time, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool
from scipy.interpolate import RectBivariateSpline

_tm=0
def stopwatch(msg=''):
    tm = time.time()
    global _tm
    if _tm==0: _tm = tm; return
    print("%s: %.2f seconds" % (msg, tm-_tm))
    _tm = tm

class BigData:
    def __init__(self, n):
        z = np.random.uniform(size=n*n*n).reshape((n,n,n))
        self.ff = []
        for i in range(n):
            f = RectBivariateSpline(np.arange(n), np.arange(n), z[i], kx=1, ky=1)
            self.ff.append(f)
        self.n = n

    def do_chunk(self, k, xi, yi):
        s = np.sum(np.exp(self.ff[k].ev(xi, yi)))
        sys.stderr.write(".")
        return s

    def do_multi(self, numproc, xi, yi):
        procs = []
        pool = Pool(numproc)
        stopwatch('Pool setup')
        for k in range(self.n):
            p = pool.apply_async( _do_chunk_wrapper, (self, k, xi, yi))
            procs.append(p)
        stopwatch('Jobs queued (%d processes)' % numproc)
        sum = 0.0
        for k in range(self.n):
            # Edit/bugfix: replaced p.get by procs[k].get
            sum += np.sum(procs[k].get(timeout=30)) # timeout allows ctrl-C interrupt
            if k == 0: stopwatch("\nFirst get() done")
        stopwatch('Jobs done')
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return sum

    def do_single(self, xi, yi):
        sum = 0.0
        for k in range(self.n):
            sum += self.do_chunk(k, xi, yi)
        stopwatch('\nAll in single process')
        return sum

def _do_chunk_wrapper(bd, k, xi, yi): # must be outside class for apply_async to chunk
    return bd.do_chunk(k, xi, yi)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stopwatch()
    n = 50
    bd = BigData(n)
    m = 1000*1000
    xi, yi = np.random.uniform(0, n, size=m*2).reshape((2,m))
    stopwatch('Initialized')
    bd.do_multi(2, xi, yi)
    bd.do_multi(3, xi, yi)
    bd.do_single(xi, yi)
```

The output:

```
Initialized: 0.06 seconds
Pool setup: 0.01 seconds
Jobs queued (2 processes): 0.03 seconds
..
First get() done: 0.34 seconds
................................................Jobs done: 7.89 seconds
Pool setup: 0.05 seconds
Jobs queued (3 processes): 0.03 seconds
..
First get() done: 0.50 seconds
................................................Jobs done: 6.19 seconds
..................................................
All in single process: 11.41 seconds
```

Timings are on an Intel Core i3-3227 CPU with 2 cores, 4 threads, running 64-bit Linux. For the actual program, the multi-processing version (pool mechanism, even if using only one core) was a factor 10 slower than the single-process version.

**Follow-up**

Unutbu's answer got me on the right track. In the actual program, `self` was pickled into a 37 to 140 MB object that needed to be passed to the worker processes. Worse, Python pickling is very slow; the pickling itself took a few seconds, which happened for each chunk of work passed to the worker processes. Other than pickling and passing big data objects, the overhead of `apply_async` in Linux is very small; for a small function (adding a few integer arguments), it takes only 0.2 ms per `apply_async`/`get` pair. So, splitting up the work in very small chunks is not a problem by itself. So, I transmit all big array arguments as indices to global variables. I keep the chunk size small for the purpose of CPU cache optimization.

The global variables are stored in a global `dict`; the entries are immediately deleted in the parent process after the worker pool is set up. Only the keys to the `dict` are transmitted to the worker procesess. The only big data for pickling/IPC is the new data that is created by the workers.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

import numpy as np, sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

_mproc_data = {}  # global storage for objects during multiprocessing.

class BigData:
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.blah = np.random.uniform(0, 1, size=size)

    def do_chunk(self, k, xi, yi):
        # do the work and return an array of the same shape as xi, yi
        zi = k*np.ones_like(xi)
        return zi

    def do_all_work(self, xi, yi, num_proc):
        global _mproc_data
        mp_key = str(id(self))
        _mproc_data['bd'+mp_key] = self # BigData
        _mproc_data['xi'+mp_key] = xi
        _mproc_data['yi'+mp_key] = yi
        pool = Pool(processes=num_proc)
        # processes have now inherited the global variabele; clean up in the parent process
        for v in ['bd', 'xi', 'yi']:
            del _mproc_data[v+mp_key]

        # setup indices for the worker processes (placeholder)
        n_chunks = 45
        n = len(xi)
        chunk_len = n//n_chunks
        i1list = np.arange(0,n,chunk_len)
        i2list = i1list + chunk_len
        i2list[-1] = n
        klist = range(n_chunks) # placeholder

        procs = []
        for i in range(n_chunks):
            p = pool.apply_async( _do_chunk_wrapper, (mp_key, i1list[i], i2list[i], klist[i]) )
            sys.stderr.write(".")
            procs.append(p)
        sys.stderr.write("\n")

        # allocate space for combined results
        zi = np.zeros_like(xi)

        # get data from workers and finish  
        for i, p in enumerate(procs):
            zi[i1list[i]:i2list[i]] = p.get(timeout=30) # timeout allows ctrl-C handling

        pool.close()
        pool.join()

        return zi

def _do_chunk_wrapper(key, i1, i2, k):
    """All arguments are small objects."""
    global _mproc_data
    bd = _mproc_data['bd'+key]
    xi = _mproc_data['xi'+key][i1:i2]
    yi = _mproc_data['yi'+key][i1:i2]
    return bd.do_chunk(k, xi, yi)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    xi, yi = np.linspace(1, 100, 100001), np.linspace(1, 100, 100001)
    bd = BigData(int(1e7))
    bd.do_all_work(xi, yi, 4)
```

Here are the results of a speed test (again, 2 cores, 4 threads), varying the number of worker processes and the amount of memory in the chunks (total bytes of the `xi`, `yi`, `zi` array slices). The numbers are in "million result values per second", but that doesn't matter so much for the comparison. The row for "1 process" is a direct call to `do_chunk` with the full input data, without any subprocesses.

```
#Proc   125K    250K    500K   1000K   unlimited
1                                      0.82 
2       4.28    1.96    1.3     1.31 
3       2.69    1.06    1.06    1.07 
4       2.17    1.27    1.23    1.28
```

The impact of data size in memory is quite significant. The CPU has 3 MB shared L3 cache, plus 256 KB L2 cache per core. Note that the calculation also needs access to several MB of internal data of the `BigData` object. Hence, what we learn from this is that it is useful to do this kind of speed test. For this program, 2 processes is fastest, followed by 4, and 3 is the slowest.

Comment: Aside: have you looked into [dask](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/)? It may make a lot of your multiprocessing tasks simpler.

Comment: @ajcr Not yet. But for now I'd like to minimize the number of external dependencies, since I may need to run this on a server where I don't have admin rights and to share it with other people who may have the same restriction.

Comment: Also this scares me: "Dask arrays implement a **subset** of the NumPy interface on large arrays". That sounds like a lot of potential work to interface with existing code.

Comment: Regarding: "about 1 second per chunk (on top of 0.1 second or so of actual calculation time when done in a single thread)"? Does that mean one call to  `pool.apply_async(_do_chunk_wrapper, ...).get()` takes 1 second (in your actual code)? whereas one call to `self.do_chunk` takes 0.1 second when run in a single thread?

Comment: @unutbu Yes. Instead of a speedup, I got a 10x slowing down... (question is updated to clarify)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try to reduce interprocess communication. 
In the `multiprocessing` module all (single-computer) interprocess communication done through Queues. Objects passed through a Queue
are pickled. So try to send fewer and/or smaller objects through the Queue.

- Do not send `self`, the instance of `BigData`, through the Queue. It is rather big, and gets bigger as the amount the amount of data in `self` grows:

  ```
  In [6]: import pickle
  In [14]: len(pickle.dumps(BigData(50)))
  Out[14]: 1052187
  ```

  Every
  time `pool.apply_async( _do_chunk_wrapper, (self, k, xi, yi))` is called,
  `self` is pickled in the main process and unpickled in the worker process.  The
  size of `len(pickle.dumps(BigData(N)))` grows a `N` increases.
- Let the data be read from a global variable. On Linux, you can take advantage of Copy-on-Write. As [Jan-Philip Gehrcke explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15415690/190597):

  > After fork(), parent and child are in an equivalent state. It would be stupid to copy the entire memory of the parent to another place in the RAM. That's [where] the copy-on-write principle [comes] in. As long as the child does not change its memory state, it actually accesses the parent's memory. Only upon modification, the corresponding bits and pieces are copied into the memory space of the child.

  Thus, you can avoid passing instances of `BigData` through the Queue
  by simply defining the instance as a global, `bd = BigData(n)`, (as you are already doing) and referring to its values in the worker processes (e.g. `_do_chunk_wrapper`). It basically amounts to removing `self` from the call to `pool.apply_async`:

  ```
  p = pool.apply_async(_do_chunk_wrapper, (k_start, k_end, xi, yi))
  ```

  and accessing `bd` as a global, and making the necessary attendant changes to `do_chunk_wrapper`'s call signature.
- Try to pass longer-running functions, `func`, to `pool.apply_async`. 
  If you have many quickly-completing calls to `pool.apply_async` then the overhead of passing arguments and return values through the Queue becomes a significant part of the overall time. If instead you make fewer calls to `pool.apply_async` and give each `func` more work to do before returning a result, then interprocess communication becomes a smaller fraction of the overall time.

  Below, I modified `_do_chunk_wrapper` to accept `k_start` and `k_end` arguments, so that each call to `pool.apply_async` would compute the sum for many values of `k` before returning a result.

---

```
import math
import numpy as np
import time
import sys
import multiprocessing as mp
import scipy.interpolate as interpolate

_tm=0
def stopwatch(msg=''):
    tm = time.time()
    global _tm
    if _tm==0: _tm = tm; return
    print("%s: %.2f seconds" % (msg, tm-_tm))
    _tm = tm

class BigData:
    def __init__(self, n):
        z = np.random.uniform(size=n*n*n).reshape((n,n,n))
        self.ff = []
        for i in range(n):
            f = interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(
                np.arange(n), np.arange(n), z[i], kx=1, ky=1)
            self.ff.append(f)
        self.n = n

    def do_chunk(self, k, xi, yi):
        n = self.n
        s = np.sum(np.exp(self.ff[k].ev(xi, yi)))
        sys.stderr.write(".")
        return s

    def do_chunk_of_chunks(self, k_start, k_end, xi, yi):
        s = sum(np.sum(np.exp(self.ff[k].ev(xi, yi)))
                    for k in range(k_start, k_end))
        sys.stderr.write(".")
        return s

    def do_multi(self, numproc, xi, yi):
        procs = []
        pool = mp.Pool(numproc)
        stopwatch('\nPool setup')
        ks = list(map(int, np.linspace(0, self.n, numproc+1)))
        for i in range(len(ks)-1):
            k_start, k_end = ks[i:i+2]
            p = pool.apply_async(_do_chunk_wrapper, (k_start, k_end, xi, yi))
            procs.append(p)
        stopwatch('Jobs queued (%d processes)' % numproc)
        total = 0.0
        for k, p in enumerate(procs):
            total += np.sum(p.get(timeout=30)) # timeout allows ctrl-C interrupt
            if k == 0: stopwatch("\nFirst get() done")
        print(total)
        stopwatch('Jobs done')
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
        return total

    def do_single(self, xi, yi):
        total = 0.0
        for k in range(self.n):
            total += self.do_chunk(k, xi, yi)
        stopwatch('\nAll in single process')
        return total

def _do_chunk_wrapper(k_start, k_end, xi, yi): 
    return bd.do_chunk_of_chunks(k_start, k_end, xi, yi)        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    stopwatch()
    n = 50
    bd = BigData(n)
    m = 1000*1000
    xi, yi = np.random.uniform(0, n, size=m*2).reshape((2,m))
    stopwatch('Initialized')
    bd.do_multi(2, xi, yi)
    bd.do_multi(3, xi, yi)
    bd.do_single(xi, yi)
```

yields

```
Initialized: 0.15 seconds

Pool setup: 0.06 seconds
Jobs queued (2 processes): 0.00 seconds

First get() done: 6.56 seconds
83963796.0404
Jobs done: 0.55 seconds
..
Pool setup: 0.08 seconds
Jobs queued (3 processes): 0.00 seconds

First get() done: 5.19 seconds
83963796.0404
Jobs done: 1.57 seconds
...
All in single process: 12.13 seconds
```

compared to the original code:

```
Initialized: 0.10 seconds
Pool setup: 0.03 seconds
Jobs queued (2 processes): 0.00 seconds

First get() done: 10.47 seconds
Jobs done: 0.00 seconds
..................................................
Pool setup: 0.12 seconds
Jobs queued (3 processes): 0.00 seconds

First get() done: 9.21 seconds
Jobs done: 0.00 seconds
..................................................
All in single process: 12.12 seconds
```

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. In my actual program, `BigData` is 37 MB, pickled. I was thinking that IPC is fast enough to handle 37 MB in a fraction of a second, but the real bottleneck seems to be that `pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(bigdata))` takes 2.8 seconds on my system! Now I can go on and reimplement the multiprocessing code for the fourth time... I'll need to make sure to get the book-keeping right for the global variable, maybe a variable name like bigdata_<process_id> and make sure that any modifications to the variable happen in the parent process.

Comment: And the reason for small chunks is that I wanted to keep all the data that's being processed in the CPU cache. Memory bandwidth seems to be a minor factor, though.

Comment: Yes, that's another important consideration. Above, I set `ks = list(map(int, np.linspace(0, self.n, numproc+1)))`. This makes the number of calls to `apply_async` equal to `numproc`. You may wish to use `ks = list(map(int, np.linspace(0, self.n, numchunks+1)))` and experiment with other values of `numchunks`.

Comment: There was a bug in my example code; it was always `get`ting the last pool entry. With that fixed, the multi-CPU run-time is more similar to yours. Still, I will get rid of the pickle/unpickle overhead!

Comment: New implementation done; added a section "Follow-up" to the question.

Comment: Just as a suggestion: since I am passing indices for the BigData global object to divide and conquer, I have implemented a method that reduces a long list of sorted integers into a list of range iterators. In some cases this idea might be useful to others, I reckon... However I have yet to test it in practice.