# Numpy matrix multiplications with multiprocessing suddenly slow down as dimension increase

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing

I want to do some large matrix multiplications using `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Suddenly, when the dimension is higher than 50, it takes an extremely long computation time.

Is there any easy way to be faster?

Here, I don't want to use shared memory like `RawArray`, because my original code randomly generate the matrix for each time.

The sample code is as follows.

```py
import numpy as np
from time import time
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial

def f(d):
    a = int(10*d)
    N = int(10000/d)
    for _ in range(N):
        X = np.random.randn(a,10) @ np.random.randn(10,10)
    return X

# Dimensions
ds = [1,2,3,4,5,6,8,10,20,35,40,45,50,60,62,64,66,68,70,80,90,100]

# Serial processing
serial = []
for d in ds:
    t1 = time()
    for i in range(20):
        f(d)
    serial.append(time()-t1)

# Parallel processing
parallel = []
for d in ds:
    t1 = time()
    pool = Pool()
    for i in range(20):
        pool.apply_async(partial(f,d), args=())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    parallel.append(time()-t1)

# Plot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.title('Matrix multiplication time with 10000/d repetitions')
plt.plot(ds,serial,label='serial')
plt.plot(ds,parallel,label='parallel')
plt.xlabel('d (dimension)') 
plt.ylabel('Total time (sec)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Due to the total computation cost of `f(d)` is the same for all `d`, the parallel processing time should be equal.

But the actual output is not.

[image]

System info:

```
Linux-4.15.0-47-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-7940X CPU @ 3.10GHz
```

> **NOTE** I want to use parallel computation as a complicated internal simulation (like `@`), not sending data to the child process.

Comment: I wonder how it works at all! If you add `print("foo")` as the very first line (before `import numpy as np`), how many times it is printed?

Comment: Only once.```foo```

Comment: This could to be system or hardware related ; maybe system memory paging ? I have a different [output](https://imgur.com/1IO3aTj) using python3.5, debian

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiprocessing.Pool makes Numpy matrix multiplication slower](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414027/multiprocessing-pool-makes-numpy-matrix-multiplication-slower)

Comment: Comparing OPs plot with Arthur's it's clear that one needs to be careful what to look for here in what context. If the use-case is fast matrix-multiplication, don't use any python-based parallelization and use a numpy-setup with multithreaded BLAS-backend, which (probably) will be impossible to beat (much more lightweight parallelism). Analyzing the jump of the parallel approach might be an interesting task, but will never lead to better real-world performance (compared to BLAS). *Some* peaks (also in serial mode) might be due to different BLAS-rel code-paths / loop-unrolling, caches and co.

Comment: What's curious is the `@` operator in the `f` function for `X = np.random.randn(a,10) @ np.random.randn(10,10)`. I have no idea what that does.

Comment: @Arthur. It's interesting. I should definitely check my hardware. Thank you.

Comment: @lucasgcb. `@` is a matrix multiplication which is equivalent to `np.dot`.

Comment: @SeungHyeonYu I got it, you are under Linux. Under Windows each process imports the main module, so you have to protect it with `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: And what does `np.show_config()` print? I suspect it is an Anaconda-related issue. It has some twists.

Comment: @ArthurHavlicek, I have output similar to yours. Python 3.7.3, Windows 10 x64

Comment: @Ralph, [your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414027/multiprocessing-pool-makes-numpy-matrix-multiplication-slower) have a problem with the sending data from the parent to child process, whereas my problem is related to the internal computation itself,

Comment: Could you plot an average of several attempts to exclude random factors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for self-reference.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48665619/8872603), I found a solution.

My `numpy` uses MKL as backend, it may be the problem that MKL multithreading collides `multiprocessing`.

If I run the code:

```py
import os
os.environ['MKL_NUM_THREADS'] = '1'
```

before importing `numpy`, then it solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just found an explanation here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/10145.
Looks like the CPU caching gets messed up when you have conflicting MKL matrix multiplications going at the same time.