# Multiprocessing with numpy causes crash

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I am trying to parallelize my code across multiple processes. The computation is mostly CPU intensive, so I decided to go for multiprocessing rather than multithreading. I am given a matrix (~300/400 elements) and a vector (~10 elements).

First, I use the pool of processes to perform `i` distinct operations on a copy the original matrix/vector, obtaining as result `i` distinct new matrix/vector pairs. In the process, I also check if a selection of columns is equal to another given matrix.

Then, for each pair obtained before, I perform other operations to check that the vector resulting from the bitwise sum of some columns of the matrix and the vector has a given weight. This last part is repeated `x` times, where `x` dictates how many columns of the matrix should I extract.

The main problem is that the computation at some point stops without any error message. For this reason, I don't know how to debug the issue at all.

Since `numpy` is already multithreading, to avoid exhausting my hardware, I also set all the thread numbers to 1. However, even if I have 96 cores, spawning a pool of 48 workers still sometimes bring all of them to 100% usage.

I have tried to simplify the code to a minimum example to just show the idea.
What can be the problem related to this code? Also, do you think this is the right approach to the problem?

```
import operator
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

import numpy as np

ENVIRONMENT = ("OMP_NUM_THREADS", "MKL_NUM_THREADS", "OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS",
               "OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS", "VECLIB_MAXIMUM_THREADS",
               "NUMEXPR_NUM_THREADS")


def _prepare_environment():
    """This is necessary since numpy already uses a lot of threads. See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58195413/2326627"""
    print("Setting threads to 1")
    for env in ENVIRONMENT:
        os.environ[env] = "1"


def _op1(matrix, vector, another_matrix, params):
    matrix2 = vector.copy()
    vector2 = vector.copy()
    # ... conditional additions of matrix2's rows and vector2 based on params...

    # Check if some columns of the matrix are equal to the other matrix given
    is_eq = np.array_equal(matrix2[:, params['range']], another_matrix)
    return (matrix2, vector2, is_eq)


def _op2(matrix, is_eq, vector, params):
    # Check bitwise sum of some columns of matrix and vector
    sum_cols_v = (matrix[:, params['range2']].sum(axis=1) + vector) % 2
    sum_cols_v_w = np.sum(sum_cols_v)
    # Check if the weight is equal to the given one
    is_correct_w = sum_cols_v_w == params['w']
    return (is_eq, is_correct_w)


def go(matrix, vector, pool):
    op1_ress = []
    for i in range(1000):  # number depends on other params, not interesting
        params = {}
        params['i'] = i
        # ...create other params...
        other_matrix = None
        # ...generate other matrix...
        res = pool.apply_async(_op1, (matrix, vector, other_matrix, params))
        op1_ress.append(res)
    # At this point we have all the results for all possible RREF
    print('op1 done')

    # We want to count the numer of matrix equal to another matrix
    n_idens = sum(i for _, _, i in map(operator.methodcaller('get'), op1_ress))
    print(n_idens)

    for x in range(5):  # number depends on other params, not interesting
        op2_ress = []
        for (matrix2, vector2, is_eq) in map(operator.methodcaller('get'),
                                             op1_ress):
            params2 = {}
            params2['x'] = x
            # ... create other params ...
            for y in range(1000):  # number depends on other params, not interesting
                params2['y'] = y
                res = pool.apply_async(_op2,
                                       (matrix2, is_eq, vector2, params2))
                op2_ress.append(res)

        n_weights = 0
        n_weights_given_eq = 0

        for is_eq, is_correct_w in map(operator.methodcaller('get'), op2_ress):
            if is_correct_w:
                n_weights += 1
                if is_eq:
                    n_weights_given_eq += 1
        print(n_weights)
        print(n_weights_given_eq)


def main():
    _prepare_environment()

    pool = Pool(48)
    rng = np.random.default_rng()
    matrix = rng.integers(2, size=(12, 28))
    vector = rng.integers(2, size=(12, 1))
    go(matrix, vector, pool)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Do you multiply or diagonalize matrices? Most `numpy` operations are single threaded. I would try to use multithreading first.

Comment: @azelcer I was under the impression that GIL was preventing me from running multiple threads at once.